# Permanently hide network disconnected icon from system tray

Tags: windows-xp, wireless-networking, icons, network-adapter, notification-area

On Windows XP, I have a disconnected Wireless connection which shows up in the System Tray.

I have gone into Network Connections dialog box and elected not to show an icon when it is disconnected, yet it remains visible.

I have gone into the Task bar properties and elected to always hide this icon, but that doesn't remove it from the system tray.

How do I remove it?

Thanks

Comment: But you don't want to disable the connection to get rid of the icon, right?  You just want it to not show up when you disconnect and also not show up when you do connect?

Comment: I want it not visible when it is disconnected, and visible when it is connected. Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try going to the device manager, finding the network adapter, right-click it, and select disable. Worked for me.

Comment: + 1 Additionally if you  right click the icon, do you see any hide option? If yes mark it.